# <li> does not display

Tags: html, css

In the middle of my page I have this `<div>` which includes a list. When I view the page source I see all the code there, but the only thing actually rendered for the user to see in the browser is the "Brand" h4 heading.    (note that this is actually generated dynamically, and this is example output)

Also I have checked in several different browsers on several different machines so I don't think thats the issue

Is there something obvious I'm missing here why my list is not displaying?

```
<div class="filter-group filter-group-brand">
     <h4>Brand</h4>

    <ul class="nav-brand ">
        <li class="collection-container aimpoint active ">
            <div class="collection-name">
                <a title="Narrow selection to products matching tag aimpoint"
                   href="/collections/firearm-accessories/aimpoint">
                    <i class="check-icon"></i> Aimpoint
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="collection-container aimshot active ">
            <div class="collection-name">
                <a title="Narrow selection to products matching tag aimshot"
                   href="/collections/firearm-accessories/aimshot">
                    <i class="check-icon"></i> Aimshot
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="collection-container barska-optics active ">
            <div class="collection-name">
               <a title="Narrow selection to products matching tag barska-optics"
                  href="/collections/firearm-accessories/barska-optics">
                   <i class="check-icon"></i> Barska Optics
               </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your css? and please share screen shot if what you want

Comment: CSS would be very helpful, maybe even a JSFiddle if you have time.

Comment: Can you post the link or put a simple fiddle to replicate the same issue. Some other styles maybe over-riding the styles that you have written. Maybe if you over-ride those by adding `!important` next to your styles may solve it.

Comment: John Doe you have to use some development aid tool like firebug or chrome console etc. debugging without this tools is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Without any CSS this works well and `<li>` elements will appear. Always think about giving your CSS code when you have a display error/problem

You must have an error in your CSS file. Check for `display:none` or `hidden` properties, etc on the following classes : `collection-name`, `new-brand`, `collection-container`.

Also you have empty `<i>` tags, just in case it's an error.